# Check if button is active

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really struggling with this piece of code.

*What I'm trying to achieve: I have an "edit button". If I press it, it'll go active and edit mode goes active. I can edit the list on the fly and it updates automatically.*

**Problem: I can get it to work for 50%. If I try to activate the button I can edit the objects. But when I deactivate the button again I can still edit the objects. Of course that shouldn't be possible.**

Here some messy code. Yeah most of it is found online and I'm trying to edit it myself...

```js
$("#editButton").click(function() {
    $("#editButton").toggleClass("active");
    if ($("#editButton").hasClass("active")) {
        $(".moveLi").on("click", function() {
            var ID = $(this).attr('id');
            $("#move_"+ID).hide();
            $("#move_edit_"+ID).show();
        }).change(function() {
            var ID = $(this).attr('id');
            var first = $("#move_edit_"+ID).val();
            var dataString = 'id=' + ID + '&name=' + first;
            $("#move_"+ID).html('<p>Saving...</p>'); // Loading image

            if (first.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "table_edit_ajax.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) {
                        $("#move_"+ID).html(first);
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                alert('Enter something.');
            }
        });

        $(".editbox").mouseup(function()  {
            return false
        });

        $(document).mouseup(function() {
            $(".editbox").hide();
            $(".text").show();
        });
    } 
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your tab key broken? This is pretty unreadable.

Comment: Please learn to format your code properly. It will make it much easier for you to read, and others to help you.

Comment: Please provide your HTML code.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry for the formatting. Was also having problems with the formatting on Stack. Was acting weird.

Comment: Well... I did it! I was quite busy so I had no time uploading it on JsFiddle... What I did: use bind + click.namespace and a bind + change.namespace and unbinding it... Thanks though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You bind a bunch of event handlers to `.moveLi` but never remove them when editing is supposed to stop:

```
if ($("#editButton").hasClass("active")) {
    $(".moveLi").on("click", function() {
        ...
    }).change(function() {
        ...
```

supplement these with something like this:

```
$(".moveLi").off("click").unbind('change');
```

Comment: Okay, so I tried to add your line of code. "Edit mode" is now disabled, but now I can't click the <li>'s anymore. The li's are expanded when you click on them. If I enable the edit mode button again, the <li>'s are still disabled.

Still trying to get it on jsFiddle... I already added PHP and the li's are entries in the database.

Comment: I did it. Your answer mos def brought me at the right path. I used bind and unbind with namespaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This line of code gave error `$(".moveLi").on("click", function()`.

It should be `$(".moveLi").click(function() {...})`

You also can use Firebug plug-in for Firefox for debugging or other built-in developer tools in other browsers, this way you can see all of the JS (and CSS) errors.

Comment: Those two lines you posted are the same thing.

Comment: @budiony no, they're definitely the same thing (assuming jquery 1.7+)

Comment: Well, we cannot be sure about the jQuery version...@6olden - please give more information or post your code to jsfiddle

Comment: No... Those functions are exactly the same `$(selector).click(function() {})` is a shortcut of `$(selected).on("click", function() {})`